# Trying to create a full bleed banner image? (Distorted)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

**So I want to create a full bleed header image with fixed height. The problem is the image is being pixelated and stretching.**

**I want something similiar to this:** http://www.laserelectrical.com.au/residential-maintenance

*Notice the header image of the page in 4k px.*

**Attempt:** I have a figure element 100% full width of screen and 200px height. Image inside is 100% of the figure element and the height is also 100% of figure element.

**Note:** I know the image in this example is 600 by 400. I've tried higher image size at 1920 by 1084, same problem? (Is there difference between image size and its resolution?)

**Is my image size that is problem or should there be a specific resolution to fix this? Or perhaps the code is incorrect?**

*I've tried different sizes of images. Is there particular size of image I should have as a standard when required for a full bleed banner (4k)?*

HTML

```css
/* ## Service Page (Page.php) */
.page .site-content {
 max-width: 100%;
}
#page-header-container {
 width: 100%;
 
  }

.service-full-bleed {
 margin: 0;
 height: 200px;

 }
.service-full-bleed img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="featured-image service-full-bleed">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"> 
  </figure>
```

Comment: do u mean pixelated or stretched?

Comment: fixed question few seconds ago ! ;)

Comment: my question remains; I see your image is stretched; is that what u want fixed?

Comment: you cannot have 100% image height in 200px div without stretching. you can `overflow:hidden;` to hide part of image that is outside of div.

Comment: Use an image with **better resolution** and **aspect ratio**. Apart from this using image in the background can be better.

Comment: Yes I've tried different sizes of images. Is there  particular size of image I should have as a standard when required for a full bleed banner (4k)? The above image is stretching, it is an example image. It either stretched or is pixelated

Comment: Larger the image better the resolution right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an image in the foreground with width and height 100%. You are basically resizing the image to the size of the container, thus stretching it if the aspect ratios are different. You can use Lwin Htoo Ko's solution and add `overflow: hidden` to `.service-full-bleed`, or you can use a background image instead:

```css
.page .site-content {
    max-width: 100%;
}
#page-header-container {
    width: 100%; 
}

.service-full-bleed {
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    background: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
    background-size:cover;
 }
```

```html
<figure class="featured-image service-full-bleed" />
```

Take note that in both cases you are only showing the top of the image. You can play with `position:relative; top: -Xpx` to shift the image by X pixel.

Comment: Or... `background-position:center;` at the .service-full-bleed to be sure the center of the image is visible ;)

Comment: `position:relative; top: -Xpx` would shift the figure element and not the background image though..

Comment: Okay now I'm using background image through css. and cover property. So its working. One quetion: the image I am now using is 1234px, do you suggest a standard width of image to use for background at minimum to reach crispier image for 4k

Comment: @Shaz, considering that 4K has a resolution of 3840 × 2160, anything smaller than that will be less crisp. It also depends on what you consider to be crisp enough.